# How should composer setup to be done for hyperledger fabric network deployment for multiple orgs on multiple physical machine

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

for deploying hyperledger fabric network using composer do i need to deploy composer per orgs (here in this case i'm using 2 orgs on 2 physical machine) or i setup of composer for all orgs is required?
anyone have idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Composer can be used against any hyperledger fabric network topology you have defined, you just need to configure connection profiles and build business network cards with these profiles for the actions you want to perform. 
The best place to understand the connection profile requirements for a multi-organisation setup is in the multi-org tutorial on the hyperledger composer documentation. 
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org
If you are planning on using the 0.17 (and higher versions) of composer then the newer documentation is here
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org (which still has some wrinkles to be sorted out but describes the new connection profile format which simplifies the number of connection profiles previously required)

Comment: One ques, the rest services which can be generated automatically by the composer for the business network, should that be deployed for each org or just 1 setup and each org hitting that?

Comment: That's an architectual decision really. You can do either. Depends on whether orgs wantto and trust each other to share resources.