# Is it possible to deploy/interact with hyperledger composer network on another machine?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

**Single business network to be deployed on multiple machines and should be able to interact across different machines.**
I am interested in deploying and accessing network in another machine. I am trying to do this by changing the connection profile (with ip and ports) of my desired host machine, but I am facing the issue:
Unable to find the response from the peers.
Is there any standard method for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can review these articles

https://discourse.skcript.com/t/running-hyperledger-composer-with-multiple-organization-on-different-host-machines/635

and

[Hyperledger fabric deployment (real network)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45378316/hyperledger-fabric-deployment-real-network)

[How should composer setup to be done for hyperledger fabric network deployment for multiple orgs on multiple physical machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280707/how-should-composer-setup-to-be-done-for-hyperledger-fabric-network-deployment-f)

You'll need to ensure that your dockerized nodes (on either physical machines etc) can 'see' each other on the IP network (standard networking stuff) and the connection profiles are configured accordingly. See also the multi-org tutorial (replace localhosts with real hosts and consider what crypto  material (certs/keys) is required 'where' - but at least it gives you an indication of the sequence from a Composer standpoint https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html (ie if using Composer v0.16.x) - if using Composer v0.17.x (and Fabric v1.1.x) then you need these docs https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html (the connection profiles are a different format).